# Shift argument in scipy.ndimage.shift

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Imagine I have a 3D image in a np array. I want to shift it along x-axis, y-axis and z-axis...

What does `shift` represent in the function [scipy.ndimage.shift](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.shift.html)? Is it a float representing a ratio? Is it the number of pixels to be shifted?

If shift=[0.5, 0, 0] is the image being shifted in the x-axis by how much?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I have found the answer. `shift` corresponds to the number of pixels being shifted.

Example 1: Imagine we have an image of shape (x, y, z), if `shift=[24, 0, 0]` then the image is shifted by 24 pixel in the x-axis.

Example 2: Imagine we have an image of shape (y, z, x), if `shift=[0, 12, 0]` then the image is shifted by 12 pixel in the z-axis.

Important: If `shift` is an int then no interpolation is performed, but if `shift` is a float the image is interpolated.

Comment: Where did you find that last bit of info? That interpolation doesn't happen for int `shift`